# enlarge div surface without changing the element size itself

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want that the smiley `div` (that shows up after user got into the wall) will cover the main maze surface without changing the smiley size: can you help me please?

here is the fiddle link:
http://jsfiddle.net/uqcLn/66/

the is the smiley divs:

```
#highlight_lose {
    height: 300px;
    width: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    margin-top: -150px;
    display: none;
}
div.sad_smileyface {
    width: 300px;
    height: 100%;
    position: relative;
    margin: 0 auto;
    border-radius: 150px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 150px;
    -moz-border-radius: 150px;
    background: #ffe632;
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(#fffe8d), to(#f6d23e));
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #fffe8d, #f6d23e);
    box-shadow: inset 0px -14px 14px rgba(0, 0, 0, .3), 0px 2px 20px rgba(0, 0, 0, .6);
    -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0px -14px 14px rgba(0, 0, 0, .3), 0px 2px 20px rgba(0, 0, 0, .6);
    -moz-box-shadow: inset 0px -14px 14px rgba(0, 0, 0, .3), 0px 2px 20px rgba(0, 0, 0, .6);
}
```

Comment: you may use CSS `scale`, e.g.: `transform: scale(1.5);` to `div.sad_smileyface`

Comment: @FabrizioCalderan i want that th grey area as i show u here: http://jsfiddle.net/uqcLn/67/ will cover all the maze

Comment: @FabrizioCalderan what you offer not working for me can u help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to change the `height` of the `#highlight_lose` from the current `300px` to `550px` (the maze's height).

Also, the `margin-top` and `top` are not required (I guess they were initially used only to center the gray area to the middle).

```
#highlight_lose {
    height: 550px;
    width: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    display: block;
    background: gray;
}
```

**EDIT:** Change your CSS as below for `div.sad_smileyface` to make sure that the smiley face doesn't have a stretched look to it.

```
div.sad_smileyface {
    width: 300px;
    height: 300px; /* modified from 100% to 300px because 100% would now mean 550px whereas initially it would have been just 300px */
    top: 25%; /* added this to position the smiley face at middle */
    position: relative;
    margin: 0 auto;
    border-radius: 150px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 150px;
    -moz-border-radius: 150px;
    background: #ffe632;
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(#fffe8d), to(#f6d23e));
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #fffe8d, #f6d23e);
    box-shadow: inset 0px -14px 14px rgba(0, 0, 0, .3), 0px 2px 20px rgba(0, 0, 0, .6);
    -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0px -14px 14px rgba(0, 0, 0, .3), 0px 2px 20px rgba(0, 0, 0, .6);
    -moz-box-shadow: inset 0px -14px 14px rgba(0, 0, 0, .3), 0px 2px 20px rgba(0, 0, 0, .6);
}
```

[**Demo Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/uqcLn/68/)

Comment: @alonblack: Yup, just now noticed (initially did not see your fiddle in the comments). Check this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/uqcLn/68/). I have modified the CSS for `div.sad_smileyface` also.

Comment: ok it works, can u pleas explain to me the logic behind the 300px X 300px as my main div is 550X550? and by the way till now when the mouseleave the smiley div the smiley fade out and now it stuck you know why?thanks very much

Comment: @alonblack: Will check on them, give me some time. For the smiley fade out, it was happening before because of the code for `$(".way").bind('mouseenter', function () {`. Now it is not possible because `.way` is no longer visible and hence a `mouseenter` on it cannot happen.

Comment: @alonblack: Check this [updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/uqcLn/69/). I have added an event handler code at the end of the current jQuery code. This way, you can fade out the gray area when the mouse is moved out of it.

Comment: @alonblack: Always glad to help mate. Coming to the 300x300px, it is because your `border-radius` is 150px. Generally the `div` becomes a circle (the smiley face) only when the radius is more than 50% of the `div`s height (and width).